# How do I have a TD not ignore it width when the table is wider than its container?

Tags: html, css

How do I have a TD not ignore it width when the table is wider than its container? This needs to work in IE7+ Chrome and FF. I'm currently having the problem in all browsers.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/CJtUf/

The HTML is:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      ... Lots mote TDs ...
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The CSS is:

```
table td { 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    width: 100px;
}
```

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0):

set `min-width`:

it seems to work in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJtUf/2/

Use it in combination with `max-width` and you can have a fixed width

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CJtUf/3/

Answer (score 0):

I know its a while since you asked, but this should work for you. 
I used a similar fix for IE7 in the past so I'm sure this could do the trick.
I'm afraid that I don't have IE7 to test and compat mode in IE10 will not load jsFiddle.

```
table td { 
border: 1px solid black; 
min-width: 100px;
width:auto !important;
width:100%;
}
```